# Return Foreign Id Java RestFul WS

Tags: java, web-services, rest, netbeans

Hi guys,

I'm new to Java Restful WS and i have a question. 
I have 2 Tables as shown below. Shape's layerId is related to Layer's id.

I created my webservice using **New Restful Web Service From Database** option and Netbeans automaticly generated my classes etc.

[image]

**Shape.java**

```
public class Shape implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "id")
private Integer id;
@JoinColumn(name = "layerId", referencedColumnName = "id" )
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Layer layerId;
 }
```

**Layer.java**

```
public class Layer implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
}
```

When i want to get any shape from web service, result is coming with Layer Object like this

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "layerId": {
        "id": 1
    }
}
```

I just want to get layerId **not Layer Object** like this

```
 {
        "id": 1,
        "layerId": 1
    }
```

Is there any way to do this ?

Thanks for reading..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution with this code

```
 public int getLayerId() {
            return layerId.getId();
        }
```

instead of this

```
public Layer getLayerId() {
        return layerId;
    }
```

in Shape.java